# Parse relation query error on swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have 2 table on parse.com. i want to make friendship system.

```
first table User -> username, email ...
Friendship Table -> RequestFrom(Related User Table), RequestTo(Related User Table), status
```

and i use this code :

```
    let usr = PFObject(className: "User")
    let friend = PFObject(className: "Friends")
    var relation = friend.relationForKey("RequestFrom")
    relation.addObject(PFUser.object())
    relation.query().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects , error ) -> Void in
        for obje in objects! {
            print(obje)
        }
    }
```

this code error.

```
"NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child.":
```

This is Friends Table
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywfpl7di4i767o7/Screenshot%202015-12-31%2014.09.40.png?dl=0
User table is classic parse User class.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you get the error? Is your app crashing? Please provide some more info.

Comment: app not crashing but parse error "NSInternalInconsistencyException" . I try relationship user and friends table. I want to list friends but it gave this error

Comment: How are you arranging your objects in Parse? Please add a picture of some of your database.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywfpl7di4i767o7/Screenshot%202015-12-31%2014.09.40.png?dl=0